# What am I missing here- simple Plutus code from tutorial?

Tags: plutus

re: https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/tutorials/basic-apps.html

Given that the explanation is ""The validator checks that the transaction, represented by scriptContextTxInfo, pays half the specified amount to each recipient.", why does the code not simply use `==half` in both cases?

````
validateSplit :: SplitData -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
validateSplit SplitData{recipient1, recipient2, amount} _ ScriptContext{scriptContextTxInfo} =
    let half = Ada.divide amount 2 in
    Ada.fromValue (valuePaidTo scriptContextTxInfo recipient1) >= half &&
    Ada.fromValue (valuePaidTo scriptContextTxInfo recipient2) >= (amount - half)```
````

Answer (score 2):

`Ada` is an integer under the hood and [`divide` rounds down](https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-tx/html/PlutusTx-Prelude.html#v:divide).

So, if `amount` is `5`, `half` would be `2` and `(amount - half)` would be `3` (totaling to `5`).